# Adding a zoom attr to a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons, `+` and `-`, to add a zoom attr to a container. I'm not sure how I can rewrite this in fewer line of code.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc0rsjkz/)

```
var ZOOM_OFFSET = 20;
var MAX_ZOOM = 60;
var MIN_ZOOM = 0;

$('.schedule-zoom .zoom-btn:not(.disable)').click(function(){
  var action_button = $(this);
  var zoom_out_button = $('.schedule-zoom .zoom-out');
  var zoom_in_button = $('.schedule-zoom .zoom-in');

  var container = $('.fixed-container');
  if (container.attr("zoom") === undefined) {
    container.attr("zoom", 0);
  }
  var zoom_value = parseInt(container.attr("zoom"));

  if (action_button.hasClass("zoom-in")) {
    zoom_out_button.removeClass("disable");

    if(zoom_value < MAX_ZOOM) {
      container.attr("zoom", zoom_value + ZOOM_OFFSET);
    } else {
      action_button.addClass("disable");
    }
  }

  else if (action_button.hasClass("zoom-out")) {

    zoom_in_button.removeClass("disable");
    if(zoom_value > MIN_ZOOM) {
      container.attr("zoom", zoom_value - ZOOM_OFFSET);
    } else {
      action_button.addClass("disable");
    }
  }

  container.html(container.attr("zoom"));


});


<div class="fixed-container">
    0
</div>

<div class="schedule-zoom">
    <button class="zoom-btn zoom-in">+</button>
    <button class="zoom-btn zoom-out">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's remove all if/else checks:

- Set `direction` to `1` or `-1` based on the button class and multiply it by ZOOM_OFFSET
- Use Math.max, Math.min to constrain zoom value in the range
- Use [.toggleClass('.foo', condition)](http://devdocs.io/jquery/toggleclass#toggleClass-className-state) to disable the buttons conditionally
- Set the attribute just once, in the end: no need to treat the absence of the attribute specially, just use a fallback `parseInt(foo) || MIN_ZOOM`

And fix some inconsistencies:

- Use camelCase names for normal variables, which is a standard JavaScript convention
- Use single or double quotes for strings consistently
- Prefer `.text(foo)` over `.html(foo)` in case of a simple text without HTML tags

```
$('.schedule-zoom .zoom-btn:not(.disable)').click(function() {
  var direction = $(this).hasClass('zoom-in') ? 1 : -1;
  var container = $('.fixed-container');

  var zoom = parseInt(container.attr('zoom')) || MIN_ZOOM;
  zoom = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(MAX_ZOOM, zoom + direction * ZOOM_OFFSET));

  container.attr('zoom', zoom).text(zoom);
  $('.schedule-zoom .zoom-in').toggleClass('disable', zoom == MAX_ZOOM);
  $('.schedule-zoom .zoom-out').toggleClass('disable', zoom == MIN_ZOOM);
});
```